# SQL Server Authentication for Website Login

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, iis

A client requested that we develop a site for them but instead of the standard ASP.NET authentication or using Active Directory accounts, they would like us to use SQL server accounts for authentication. (That is, an account using SQL Server authentication.)

This website would be exposed to the public Internet and would have users that are not employed by the client and the client's Active Directory is not available in their DMZ.

So I have a few questions on this:

1) Is this a good idea? (Our gut feeling is that it's not.)

2) How should we best go about doing this?

Off the top of my head, the best answer I can come up with for how to do this would be to dynamically build a connection string based off the credentials the user enters in a web form. If the connection is successful, continue to the site. Otherwise, kick them back out to the login page. (And, of course, make sure accounts get logged out in the event of too many failed logins.)

Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ask them, WHY? Seems like an oddly specific request that could lack understanding on their part, perhaps. I'd [start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee798283(v=cs.20).aspx) though

Comment: They believe it will be cheaper to do this than to implement a more standard forms-based authentication. Given the extra security issues around this, we'll probably come back with an estimate showing it wouldn't be.

Comment: I'd hope your estimate will be noticeably higher than other proposals to steer them away or at least make it worth your while, somewhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is this a good idea? (Our gut feeling is that it's not.)

There are a few problems using this.  Notably, you would have to run your application as an escalated user to perform user maintenance-- add/inactivate users, change passwords, etc...  Running a web-app with escalated permissions on the database is generally frowned on.  If you run this kind of thing outside of your application, then you'll need to get your DBA to run all the user maintenance stuff, which isn't fun.  Also, if you have requirements around password complexity, password rotation, etc., you may find SQL Server authentication lacking over what would be available in AD, for example.

> 2) How should we best go about doing this?

You can easily test credentials provided by attempting to login to SQL Server using the supplied credentials.  You can read the connection string from your configuration settings, but then load it into a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` object (in `System.Data.SqlClient`somewhere), manipulate it to use the supplied credentials, and then connect using the result of that manipulation to test if the credentials were valid.

You would want to use that only for testing your login.  After that, you could go back to using your normal connection strings.

Comment: Why would I want to use the normal connection string? (Note that we may be forced to use SQL Authentication all around due to the lack of Windows authentication. I'm checking on that.) If we're forced to use SQL authentication all around, is there any reason to use shared credentials for everyone? Thank you.

Comment: If this is a web-app, then connection pooling would be defeated by everyone using unique connection strings.  Performance will be better and permissions easier to manage, assuming you don't need table-level access control, if you use a traditional service account for your web application rather than unique logins for each data connection.  It depends, of course, on your application which way makes more sense

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.